# i can rdp windows server 2016 dc but i can't access server manager or users and computers of active directory

Tags: active-directory, permissions, domain-controller, windows-server-2016, user-accounts

i am a beginer in windows server administration, i am curently working on lab about active directory, so i set up a windows server 2016 DC in whitch i created two OU, in those OUs i created a multiple users,

i want to delegate controle of those OUs to a group of those users that i created and i want this group to be able to create modify and delete any object in those OUs and their sub OUs but not be able to read write or modify other OUs. in other words, and correct me if i'am wrong. i dont want this group to be a member of the domain admins

so as the title of my question says:

i want the menbers of this group to be able to rdp the domain controller (wich i managed to configure)

and be able to lunch the server manager, dns, users and computer of ad tools wich i can't figure out because once i opened rdp session with a member of this group the server manager does not lunch and when i try to lunch it as well as dns or users and computer of AD tools i get the folloing mmc popup that asks me for administrator cridentials,
[see the mmcpopup picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz4SH.png)

is it possible to have this configution? and if yes, how?

thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Ok every Start ist easy, so allowing a basic User to lgoin to a Server isa seperaten right. The server Manager needs local Administrator rights on the server to change Things so UAC does the job very well :)

Answer (score 0):

Best bet would be to install RSAT for AD and DNS on their workstation, this would allow them to open what they need without being able to login to a DC.

You want only your domain admins in your DC.

Once you delegate rights to the users, they should have access to make the changes that are needed.